# Fullcalendar events are not up-to-date

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm passing events to Fullcalendar. Everything is displayed properly. But when I'm getting modified data (For example I resized the event) to save from the Fullcalendar I'm seeing that the data is outdated (Date, hours and minutes are not valid).

Fullcalendar initialization:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    locale:'pl',
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    slotDuration: '00:15:00',
    droppable: true,
    drop: function(date) {
        alert("Dropped on " + date.format());
    },
    defaultDate: date,
    defaultView: 'agendaDay',
    editable: true,
    timeFormat:'H(:mm)',
    minTime: "07:00:00",
    maxTime: "21:00:00",
    events: eventsArray,
});
```

The way I'm getting events from the calendar:

```
var eventsArray = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
```

---

**I've found the solution.**

The problem was that I had to format end and start date using moment.js `.format()` function.